# how to get variables from php using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, variables

I want to send a value to a php script and execute it, after i want to get variables from the php script and show it using AJAX
this is the PHP script

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$_POST['username'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username="'.$username.'" ');
if ($req = mysql_fetch_array($sql) ) { 
$result = '<div class"result">' . $req['firstname']. "</div>";}
echo $result;
?>
```

and here is html and AJAX

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ajaxButton").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:'toAction.php',
            data:{username: $('#username').val()},
            type:'POST',
        });
    });
});
</script>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
<input type="button" value="Find" id="ajaxButton"/>
<div id="result"></div>
```

in `<div id="result"></div>` I want to show `$result` .
How can I do this, and I m very sorry about my English ...

Comment: you want to echo json_encode( $result ); you might also need to set the header such as  header('application/json'); before the echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to send the result back using the `success` callback to display `$result` like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ajaxButton").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:'toAction.php',
            data:{username: $('#username').val()},
            type:'POST',
            success: function(data) {
              $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like that.

```js
  $.ajax({
            url:'toAction.php',
            data:{username: $('#username').val()},
            type:'POST',
            success: function(phpData){
            //PHP data can be used he!
            alert(phpData);
            }
        });
```