# Ajax query not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have spent some time looking at examples of Ajax, sending a variable to PHP and getting back a different variable.  This is from another page ([how to get variables from php using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570690/how-to-get-variables-from-php-using-ajax)) but it seems something is not working for me.  I do not get an error, just no actions appear to happen. My goal is to simply post some data to the php page and get variables back and put them in different DIVs.

htmlpage.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ajaxButton").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:'phppage.php',
            data:{username: $('#username').val()},
            type:'POST',
            success: function(data) {
              $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
<input type="button" value="Find" id="ajaxButton"/>
<div id="result">This should change on click</div>
</body>
</html>
```

phppage.php

```
<?php

$_POST['username'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$result = '<div class="result">' .$username. "</div>";
echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: This code will definitely produce an error, since `$` is undefined.  (You forgot to include jQuery.)  Check the browser console for errors.  Just because one doesn't show in a pop-up doesn't mean there's no error.

Comment: `I do not get an error` - you're not looking in the right place in that case

Comment: put this -> "<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>" between => <head></head> tags

Comment: @David - Goodness, you can tell I need some mental therapy. You are correct, once included it worked.  I can't believe I forgot that.  If you want to post your response as an answer, I'll mark it since that was actually what was wrong.

Comment: Is there any way I could retrieve just one of the variables if phppage.php were to have more than one variable?  Like $result1 $result2 etc.

Comment: If you wanna show same result in 2different div yes you can. If you wanna 2different result in 2 different div yes again but you must parse coming response from php file with json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the whole scripts of yours? If it is, I think that you don't import the jquery in your frontend scripts

Please add the jquery in your code, for example :

```
<script   src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```